# An Army of Greed - Henrik and Wulf are stuck

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

I'm at the mission "An Army of Greed" from the falskaar mod and I NEED to end it to be able to travel back to skyrim.

I killed the bandits there and the problem now is, that the people there are stuck in the "offensive Mode" they hold their sword like they're waiting for an enemy an I cannot talk to at least Henrik, what I'd have to do.

I tried the spell calm and fear, nothing changed. I also tried out some reset-cheats, but non of them was "valid", I don't know what I did wrong, but has anyone an idea about this problem?

Comment: I've had this happen to me too.  You'll have to reload from a save from the beginning of the quest and try again.

Comment: I hope there is another solution for this problem. :(

Comment: have you tried waiting to pass some time?

Comment: @spartacus:
Yes, I also fast travelled to other points of the map to "respawn" the NPC's but that didn't change anything. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after a couple of weeks I wanted to play again and the bug was still there. I reloaded and now it works, so here is my tipp for anyone else who meets this bug:

**Problem:**
I FIRST unleashed Henrik and his "family" (sneaked in the house) and fought after that against the bandits. I think that was the problem, but I'm not sure. After you kill the bandits, you get a quest "unleash them". I did this before I killed the bandits and I think the game couldn't handle this.

**Solution:**
Kill all bandits, THEN unleash the others. :)

If it's already to late for you, I think reloading an old savegame will be inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem several times. The first time I was in god mode because I was tired of dealing with the all the crap just getting down to the docks (but that's not important). I tried again out of god mode to see if that did anything, but it didn't; and my third attempt was the same. Now each time I tried this, I entered the dock area by going down the hill through the gap between the building and the rocky area.

But the fourth time, I entered the dock area along the shoreline. I also read the phrase "Kill the bandits at the docks" literally, meaning kill the bandits in the area of the docks (because I was fighting the bandits on the hill rather than in the docks), and it worked. I also didn't use any shouts or destruction spells the fourth time (I had been during my other three attempts). I kited them around the firepit (using my axe, shield, and conjured bow) and used fast healing.

Long story short: **enter dock area along the shore, kill bandits in dock area, don't use shouts or destruction spells**.

I hope this was helpful, sorry about the long explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you get stuck and dont have a usable savegame, then download Tania the Hermit as follower, dont make her follow you. You can "portal" to her by using a spell that is given to you when you install this mod.